# Libgdx Hud Stage Button not Listening events

Tags: libgdx, touch, imagebutton, hud

I am trying to implement a HUD stage on top of the current stage. I am able to render and draw the HUD stage but its buttons' touch events are not responding.

I am calling my drawHUD() from my draw() method of GameScreen. Code for drawHUD() is

```
public void drawHud(int scoreVal){
    Hud.this.getCamera().update();
    Hud.this.hudSpriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(Hud.this.getCamera().combined);
    hudSpriteBatch.begin();
    scoreStr = "Score: " + scoreVal;
    glyphLayout.setText(scoreFont, scoreStr);
    halfWidth = glyphLayout.width/2;
    halfHeight = glyphLayout.height/2;
    scoreFont.draw(hudSpriteBatch, scoreStr, EatGame.CAMERA_WIDTH/2 - halfWidth, EatGame.CAMERA_HEIGHT - halfHeight);
    hudSpriteBatch.end();       
}
```

I have added a listener to my pauseBtn like this when creating my HUD

```
pauseBtn.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("PauseBtn Touched");
            return false;
        }
}
```

I have also tested by setting the bounds of the button, but it is not responding to events.
Thanks for reading and helping.

Comment: touchDown must return a boolean. Does this compile at all?

Comment: Edited now, I was trying to remove some code.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you use the [scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) API for implementing buttons and stuff like that. The `Stage` class is responsible for handling the events on the correct actor. Look at the Stage#touchDown() how they do it. If you want to implement this on your own, you would have to implement a global touch-listener and check, if the coordinates are inside the bounds of the button and then call `fire` on the button with the correct `Event` object.

I would highly recommend to use the scene2d api, its far more easier then to write your own hit-detection-firing-event-system.

Comment: I am using ImageButton which indirectly uses Actor as its parent. So basically I am already using scene2d. Moreover I tried by using Actor class, but got no success. Might be I am missing something.

Comment: You have to use the `Stage` class, otherwise it won't work. Maybe this tutorial is of more use to you: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/11/27/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-1.aspx In my application I tried to implement this button stuff on my own but then I went back to scene2d because its much easier, I can only recommend spending some time with this framework.

Comment: My Hud class is extending 'Stage' class.

Comment: Why are you drawing the button itself? You can call draw on the stage...? And don't forget act. Like this: 
stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
 stage.draw();

Comment: Thanks morpheus05, Done that. I have tried Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(Hud.ths) but now touch events are not working on my GameScreen. I am able to set InputProcessor either on HUD stage or on GameScreen (Screen and Stage). How can I handle this?

Comment: I have heard about something called InputMultiplexer, should I use that?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use InputMultiplexer for taking input events from both the stages. I have done this that way.

```
    InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
    multiplexer.addProcessor(GameScreen.this);
    multiplexer.addProcessor(hud);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```

This way it will receive events from both the stages. GameScreen and Hud are Stages.